# Need advice for disk access program

Tags: programming-languages, disk

I'm envisioning a program I will need to write and need some advice on the language.  I will need to be doing raw disk access so I can display hex data, scroll or jump around on the disk, and do calculations from the data.  I have been using Java the most and it's portability between OSes for my other projects is certainly a benefit, but raw disk access either isn't possible, would require JNI, or may be possible on *nix when you can access disks as "files".  I keep reading different things.  By the way I can handle this type of work using Files in Java, but in this project I need to be able to access the disk so disk imaging to files beforehand isn't needed.

It would be nice to make it as portable as I could since there is a real benefit to using different OSes, but it may not be worth it and I should just stick with Windows and a native compiling language.  Is there any existing JNI code that could help?  I have experience in other languages but I haven't used C++ in a long time.  Should I forget about Java and tryout C#?  Someone told me that Python has libraries available for this type of thing despite it being an interpreted language so what about Python?  What would be best for the project?  What would be good for me to learn?

Searching around for raw disk access, Java, Python, does not seem to give any useful results.  Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**
It seems like this will be quite involved, learning what I need to know, and then learning that. It's too bad I couldn't use disk images instead because then I'd be able to start working on it immediately in Java, which I'm comfortable with and I know I could make a good product.  I've gotten great throughput in other raw data processing projects with Java so that doesn't worry me.  Plus it would be truly portable.  Hmm might have to consider it more.  I'd probably need a big azz storage system to hold all the images though :)

**UPDATE**
Just a note for anyone that finds this question... I have figured out this works just by specifying the disk for the File using the PhysicalDrive notation (in Windows) like the answer below by hunsricker. However there are some issues. First if you do a "exists" check File.exists(), it says the file does not exist. Also, the file size is zero, and when I get a "java.io.IOException: The drive cannot find the sector requested" is the way I know I'm at the end of the file. And the worst part- I was getting some odd runtime errors doing this when I was reading some bytes and skipping some (64) bytes in a loop. I altered my program a bit to read different amounts and that changed where the error occurred. I was using BufferedInputStream instead of RandomAccessFile like hunsricker below by the way, not sure if it makes a difference. My only answer for this issue is that since I'm doing physical disk access, it doesn't like that I am not reading in even 512 byte sectors or 1K blocks or such. Indeed when I read even 1K, 2K, 512bytes, etc., and don't skip anything, it works fine and runs to the end. The errors I saw were java.io.ioexception "incorrect function" and java.io.ioexception "the parameter is incorrect". There was no rhyme or reason to them. Then I made image files of the same data and ran my program on those and it would do any combination of reading and skipping bytes with no problem. Physical disk access was more picky I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking by myself for a possibility to access raw data of a physical drive. And now as I got it to work, I just want to tell you how. You can access raw disk data directly from within java ... just run the following code with administrator priviliges:

```
    File diskRoot = new File ("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0");
    RandomAccessFile diskAccess = new RandomAccessFile (diskRoot, "r");
    byte[] content = new byte[1024];
    diskAccess.readFully (content);
```

So you will get the first kB of your first physical drive on the system. To access logical drives - as mentioned above - just replace 'PhysicalDrive0' with the drive letter e.g. 'D:'

oh yes ... I tried with Java 1.7 on a Win 7 system ...

RageDs link brougth me to the solution ... thank you :-)

Comment: Does this really work?  Why does everyone say you can't do this?  Does this work in Linux?

Comment: Yes it works, just did it very similarly using BufferedInputStream for better speed.

Comment: Ok it works with several caveats, see my UPDATE to the question above.

Comment: Seems to work only in read-only mode. "rw" will throw `FileNotFoundException (The parameter is incorrec)` :-(

Comment: And I am sure on Linux, for instance, you can use the device files in `/dev` -- they certainly have much the same function as the above does for Windows. Meaning that in the end, you can easily use Java to access the actual disk, but may probably not do so without privilege escalation, and that's a good thing -- *writing* data to persistent storage directly, data that is typically managed by a file system, puts responsibility for all the data the disk contains, entirely on your program and its users.

Answer (score 0):

Disk access will depend on the disk's particular drivers. And since this is such a low-level task, I doubt Java/Python would have such support (these languages are generally used for fast, high-level software package development). Since you will probably not be aware of the disks' particular hardware implementations, you will probably have to end up using an operating system API (which is OS-dependent of course). I would recommend looking into C and/or the particular assembly language for the architecture you plan to do this work on. Then, I would recommend continuing your search to find the appropriate API for your target OS.

**EDIT**

For Windows, a good place to start is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027). More specifically, MSDN's [CreateFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) is probably a function you would be interested in.

Comment: Yes I will need to use an OS's API.  So Windows API.  I definitely don't want to write specific code to do something the OS can do for me.  Why assembly?  The higher level the better.

Comment: Assembly would be more directed to performance (and sometimes C can't do everything you need it to). In any case, C will most likely be ok. I have updated my response with some links which may be good starting points.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I actually have come across that Direct Drive Access page at MS several times.  I know of, and have used, an open source VMFS driver for accessing VMFS volumes (from whatever OS) that is coded in Java and it works well using that "\\.\PhysicalDriveN" notation.  I wonder how that works.  I may have to read some code.

I've been looking at books and may need something like - Windows System Programming http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Microsoft-Technology/dp/0321657748/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1321650332&sr=8-1